# Jetpack Compose Preview and emulator not the same

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to kotlin and Jetpack Compose. I'm following this [Basic CodeLab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics#0) . And I'm using latest android studio (Giraffe). Unlike the tutorial, the Preview from Android Studio and actual running views are not the same (even the color). Here is the difference.

[image]

My code is ..

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.zwin.codelab_jpcbasic.ui.theme.CodeLabJPCBasicTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CodeLabJPCBasicTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp(names: List<String> = listOf("World", "Compose")) {
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 4.dp), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top) {
            for (name in names) {
                Greeting(name = name)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    var expanded = remember {mutableStateOf(false) }
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 4.dp)) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)) {
                Text("Hello,")
                Text("$name")
            }
            OutlinedButton(onClick = {
                expanded.value = expanded.value.not()
            }) {
                Text(if(expanded.value) "Show more" else "Show less", color = Color.White)
            }
        }
    }
}


@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 320, heightDp = 800)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    CodeLabJPCBasicTheme {
        MyApp()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because inside `onCreate` you are use `Greeting` composable but inside `GreetingPreview` you are use `MyApp` composable. Which is different composable. That is why the preview and emulator not match. In short, you have to use `MyApp` inside `onCreate` as shown in the tutorial.

Comment: True. Didn't notice that.